# Javascript Express Checkout - are they IPN compatible?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm currently using PayPal buttons on a site. When the transaction completes, my backend system gets an IPN with the details to process and dispatch the purchased item.

The javascript-driven express checkout looks nice and fancy, but I'm confused by the mixed statements and documentation. Do I **need** to implement WebHooks to achieve the same with the newer express checkout? Or do I still receive IPNs?

I also have subscription buttons that won't use the express checkout yet. So I need to know if I can use IPNs to process both purchase types, or if JS-express checkouts only send webhooks and not IPNs.

I want to avoid signing up to webhooks and then receiving both webhooks and IPNs for the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I can actually test this in the sandbox by creating a sandbox merchant account, logging in on sandbox.paypal.com, and setting up IPNs there.

**Yes**, IPNs are still sent for the Javascript Express Checkout functionality. Webhooks are optional.